# How can I merge Multiple Header Edit directives in Apache2?

Tags: http-headers, apache2, httpd.conf, apache-config

I have an requirement to edit outgoing Header values in Apache2. I am using the below for example

```
Header edit Location "<my regex>" "resultant location"
```

The expression above works great when this is the only Header Edit Location directive within my conf files in the same vhost.

When I add another Header Edit Location directive, such as below, it seems like Apache "ANDs" them and I only get to "resultant location" if the incoming Location satisfies the regex criteria in both the Header Edit Directives.

```
Header edit Location "<my regex2>" "resultant location"
```

What I am looking for is something like

If my incoming Location Matches either the regex criteria, it goes to the resultant location. The resultant location will remain the same for both regex evaluations

```
Header edit Location "<my regex>" "resultant location"
```

OR

```
Header edit Location "<my regex2>" "resultant location"
```

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible and if yes, how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance